# how to enable fingerprint log in Dell 5370 laptop in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, dell, sensors

My Dell 5370 laptop has a built-in fringerprint sensor that was working in Windows but after installing Ubuntu 18.04 it is not being shown.

I tried to **[settings/details/user]**  but I don't get any option to enable it. Then I tried `sudo pam-auth-update` but there also I don't get any option to enable it.

I got the following options only to enable

```
 [*] Unix authentication                                                 
 [*] Register user sessions in the systemd control group hierarchy       
 [ ] Create home directory on login                                      
 [*] GNOME Keyring Daemon - Login keyring management
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue. After much searching here's how I got it working

> sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd

After this reboot.

Goto Settings >> Users and enable fingerprint login.

Finally to use fingerprint for Sudo open terminal and type

> sudo pam-auth-update

Enable Fingerprint authentication.

Cheers!

Comment: in User I don't have any such option like enable fingerprint.
(I am using ubuntu 18)